# How to sort columns alphabetically in a database table?

Tags: excel, sorting, spreadsheet, openoffice-calc

I know this issue could be taken as a basic question, but I don´t ask it in the 'classic' way, so I don't want to know how to sort elements that are into a column.

I have  a table in which I need to sort alphabetically the first row (column names), moving jointly the content of each column. Is this possible?

I don't care about what software I would need to use, but I'll be very pleased if the provided solution is done in any spreadsheet, like Excel, Open/LibreOffice Calc, Gnumeric, etc.

Comment: - 1, this is a very basic question had you even attempted to sort in Excel on one column where there was data in the next column you would have recieved the pop-up to expand the sort columns.

Comment: Why do you assume that I'm an Excel user? After doing several searches in Google (and even in some wiki pages) I didn't find the solution for my problem. No one is born taught, Mr. Arrogant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in excel 2007+
Data-Sort, click Options button, choose left to right, then choose row1